# Как быстро удалить часть данных в БД MS SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Один реквизит в таблице весит около 20 Гб.

Этот реквизит по сути не важен, то есть мне уже не нужны данные, которые были записаны в БД в том году, но важны будут данные этого реквизита этого года.

Нужно уменьшить эту цифру. Мой вариант решения проблемы:

Хочу занулить данные этого реквизита, чтобы уменьшить память.
Этот реквизит может содержать сотни тысяч символов, всего строк на зануление 850 000

Мой запрос:

```
update _Document167
set _Fld685 = 0
where _Fld670 < '2023-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Запрос выполнялся 3 часа и я не выдержал и отменил, отмена запроса происходила полчаса.

Подскажите, все ли я правильно делаю для моей цели? и стоит ли просто поставить запрос на выполнение и ждать часами или можно попробовать что-то другое для более быстрого достижения результата?

Comment: Я бы в данном случае воспользовался поговоркой "Утро вечера мудренее" и создал бы джобик с разовым выполнением, например, на полночь, а утром довольствовался результатом.

Comment: Есть ли индекс по _Fld670? Колонка _Fld685 текстовая? Если да, то почему вы пытаетесь вставить туда число?

Comment: @AndrewNikolaev Да ещё и чанками - на всякий случай... тыщ по десять записей за чанк.

Comment: Да, текстовая, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Хотя нет, я брал отдельную запись в данных и заменял ее на 0 таким же кодом и все нормально было, все сработало

Comment: Увидев вопрос с таким названием, я собрался рассказать про виды компрессии, существующие в Sql Server. Полагаю, надо переименовать его. Что-то вроде: Как быстро удалить часть данных.

Comment: Иногда БД начинает летать после обновления статистики. Встречались такие случаи в практике. Это когда забивают на обслуживание БД (нет знающего DBA). Правда, в данном случае это вряд ли. К тому же само обновление статистики может занять много времени.

Comment: А индексы у вас есть на этих полях? Можно попробовать выключить индекс на обновляемом поле, а на поле, по которому отбор идёт, наоборот индекс должен быть включен. А вообще да, если всё так долго, то напишите цикл, который будет, скажем, отбирать 10 тыщ записей за раз и их обнулять с коммитом. Я как-то так делал на рабочей базе, которая иначе бы никогда не обновилась, а всё время лочилась из-за того, что туда кто-то данные вставляет, а у меня транзакция никак не заканчивается и мешает этой вставке.

Comment: может вам там вдобавок таблицу партицировать, раз данные за прошлые годы не нужны?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему написанием цикла:

```
DECLARE @RowsUpdated INTEGER
SET @RowsUpdated = 1

WHILE (@RowsUpdated > 0)
BEGIN
UPDATE TOP (1000) _Document168
SET _Fld748 = '' 
WHERE _Fld733 < '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND _Fld748 != ''
SET @RowsUpdated = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Если раньге надо было ждать более 3 часов и не дождаться, то тут за 40 минут все обработалось